# Jquery Tabs ie7 horizontal scroll with overflow

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, overflow

We have a fixed jquery ui tab that has an accordion in the content of the tab.  In every browser when the height of the content is exceeded by the Content of the Accordion, the Accordion header resizes to fit horizontally and a vertical scroll bar allows you to scroll down the text.  In ie7, it seems like the Accordion isn't properly resized, which creates the unwanted horizontal scroll bar.

I'm not worried about ie6 but ie7 is still 20% of our users.  Here are two examples followed by the code.

http://idrinksport.com/beta/ieissues/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the style attribute 'overflow-x: hidden' to your div container with the id 'search'. That should remove the horizontal scroll bar.

```
<div class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="search" style="overflow-x: hidden;">
```

Comment: We tried that, although it did stop the scrollbar, it would cut off the content to the right.

We tried the *padding-right feature and it seems to be a workaround for ie7